# Android create vertical carousel with stacked views

Tags: android, android-viewpager, stack, carousel

I am trying to implement this carousel style thing. It would be basically stacked fragments above each other and I could scroll through them. When I scroll the very front one would move intuitively to back. Does anyone know any library for that or is it easily doable with ViewPager? Or do I have to implement the whole thing custom myself?

Thanks :)

[image: Example]

Comment: If your are successful. Would you please share the code.

Comment: This one is a long time ago. If you don't want to implement this on your own then the Android Arsenal is a good site to look for 3rd party libs.

Comment: I looked every where but could not found anything exactly like this. I want to make carousel like Android when 'Overview' button is pressed or like Chrome for android tab selection carousel.

Comment: Well, that is different a lot from what I've been doing. If you won't find any library for that then I guess you'll have to implement that on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your own carousel like this.Please check **StackView** and **ViewFlipper** also.

Comment: Can you please post any reference links, even i have to implement same.